# How does shortest path work in pgrouting?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I'm trying to find how the implementation of shortest_path() in pgRouting works.

This is the function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path(sql text, source_id integer,target_id integer, directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)  
RETURNS SETOF path_result AS '$libdir/librouting', 'shortest_path'  
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT  
  COST 1  
  ROWS 1000;  
ALTER FUNCTION shortest_path(text, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) OWNER TO postgres;
```

My questions are:

1. How does it calls the .c file and how it passes the parameters to it (I believe it's dijkstra.c file, correct?)
2. How can I take that .c file and compile it with the debug info it has in order to see how it works so I can understand it better?

Comment: Do you want to use pgRouting to calculate shortest paths or are you trying to understand how the code works?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the code works and I would like to know how I can compile the .c file in order to take a bigger picture from the code

Comment: I really need to know how it works so could someone please help me..

Comment: This question is pretty much off-topic here. It's much more about general programing knowledge. I can migrate it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the source](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/dijkstra/src/dijkstra.c) for dijkstra.c.  You can read this code to see what the function is doing.  The SQL you posted just shows the binding to the native C function.

Comment: Direct link updated and here's top-level link to the project: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting